# Objective-c PickerView displays memory locations instead of object variable names from singleton

Tags: objective-c, singleton, nsarray, uipickerview

Overview: I've got a MapKit map, a PickerView, and a static array of weapon objects (Each weapon having some member variable data).  The intent is to use the picker view and display some information on my map (range, name).

Need some help with the array of objects stored in my Singleton.  I'm passing the array successfully to the map but the picker is displaying the memory locations of the objects instead of the name.

SingletonFile.m where I create the array of objects

```
static dispatch_once_t pred;
static SingletonFile *shared = nil;
dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
    shared = [[SingletonFile alloc] init];
    shared.theWeapons = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:
                         @[[[weapon alloc] initWithName:@"M16" weaponPicName:@"M16 Pic Name"],
                        [[weapon alloc] initWithName:@"M20" weaponPicName:@"M20 Pic Name"],
                           [[weapon alloc] initWithName:@"M3" weaponPicName:@"MyName"]
                           ]];

    //This is my attempt to create a second array with only the weaponPicName's from theWeapons array created above.
    shared.theWeaponNameArray = [shared.theWeapons valueForKey:@"weaponPicName"];
    //This line produces the error, not key value coding-compliant for the key weaponName
    //weaponName and weaponPicName are a part of the weapon object
});
return shared;
```

Weapon.m constructor for the weapon object

```
-(id)initWithName:(NSString*)weaponName weaponPicName:(NSString*)weaponPicName {

    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _weaponName = weaponName;
        _weaponPicName = weaponPicName;
    }
    return self;
}
```

MapViewController.m is where I get theWeapons array from my singleton class

```
//Initialize tableNames to the singleton name array for use in picker
self.tableNames = [SingletonFile weaponSingleton].theWeapons;
```

MapViewController.m (further down) is my picker code.

```
- (IBAction) pickType:(id)sender {

    arrayPickerRows = self.tableNames;

    [ActionSheetStringPicker showPickerWithTitle:@"Select"
                                            rows:arrayPickerRows
                                initialSelection:0
                                       doneBlock:^(ActionSheetStringPicker *picker, NSInteger selectedIndex, id selectedValue) {
                                           selectedRow = [arrayPickerRows objectAtIndex:selectedIndex];
                                           [self typePickerDone:sender];
                                       }
                                     cancelBlock:^(ActionSheetStringPicker *picker) {
                                         NSLog(@"Block Picker Canceled");
                                     }
                                          origin:sender];
}
- (void) typePickerDone:(UIButton*) sender {


    [self.WeaponPickerbutton setTitle:selectedRow forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

I'm sure the answer has to do with accessing the weaponName of the objects.  I've tried to create an array of weaponNames from the array of objects using valueForKey but it was saying my keys were non value compliant.

(Also aware I can do all this with a .plist but I'm trying to learn Singletons and work with arrays of objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `arrayPickerRows` stores a array of the weapons. When you set the title for the button, so when you use `[arrayPickerRows objectAtIndex:selectedIndex]`, you will get the address of a weapon at index `selectedIndex`.

In your code, you don't have the definition for the variable `selectedRow`. However, it should be of class `weapon`. When setting the name of the button, you should use the following code:

```
[self.WeaponPickerbutton setTitle:selectedRow.weaponName forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Thanks, that got me 90% there.  My selectedRow was an NSString.  Changing it to a class didn't fix the display of the rows in the picker but it got the button working.  I was able to go back and create a second array of just the names for use in the picker rows.